# Shall we implement the "No AI" banner?

Tags: discussion

Re: Meta [Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/261421)

Stack Exchange is rolling out an option to include a banner when a user is writing an answer explaining the site's policy on AI-generated content.

> All sites in the Stack Exchange network will be able to opt in (the feature is off by default, network-wide)
>
> We will initially offer two banner text options that all sites in the
> Stack Exchange network can opt-in to. Those options are the following:
>
> `**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more`
>
> `**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more`
>
> The banner will display once users select the answer field
>
> The “new contributor” banner will no longer be shown in the answer
> field
>
> All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option
> to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner
> again

So we have the option to

- Do nothing; keep the current "be nice to new users" banner
- Disallow answers from generative AI tools
- Allow answers from generative AI tools but require users to label them as such

Please read the Q on Meta Stack Exchange (linked above) to see all of the details (the quoted bit is an excerpt) and leave your thoughts in the answers to this question, including ideas about what should be in G&FH.SE's **Learn More** article, should we decide to implement the new banner.

Answer (score 5):

I think we should opt-in for:

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on G&FH SE.

Answer (score 2):

I would also plump for no AI.

At the moment, I have seen too many stories of AI generated content that includes citations, but on examination, the citations are simply text created to look like a citation. The AI has learnt what a citation looks like but not the process of creating one. I am utterly unclear how machine learning can learn process. Until I am convinced that AI understands process, I cannot accept it at face value.